# Webservice stubs in Blackberry app

Tags: blackberry, webservices-client

I am currently developing a proof of concept Blackberry application that uses RPC calls. I have also developed a very basic server application in .Net that simply timestamps a string sent to it and returns it to the client. I have been able to connect to the server app using a .Net client and a Java client so I am fairly confident it works correctly.

For the Blackberry client application I used [Java Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/download-135801.html) to generate stubs for the RPC calls. I then used these calls in a basic Blackberry app to try and replicate the results of the .Net and Java clients, but it keeps throwing exceptions. I am not sure if I am using stubs correctly.

```
    pushScreen(new HelloWorldScreen("Initiating communication"));
    try {
        IHelloService_Stub stub = new IHelloService_Stub();
        String result = stub.hello("Hello From Blackberry");
        pushScreen(new HelloWorldScreen(result));
     } catch (RemoteException e) {
        pushScreen(new HelloWorldScreen(e.getMessage()));
     }
```

At present I am running everything locally. The server runs as localhost and the Blackberry app is running on the Blackberry simulator. I have used the Blackberry browser to check if I can reach the service and I can so its not the network connection that is the issue.

The exception thrown is the following:

> java.io.interruptedIOException: Local connection timed out after ~ 120000

Comment: What exceptions does it throw?

Comment: It seems to be a timeout exception

Answer (score 2):

Try appending ;deviceside=true to your URL.  That should eliminate the need for using the MDS simulator.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it matters *where* MDS is installed. I had originally installed in in C:\Program Files(x86)\Research in Motion but then read a post elsewhere that suggested installing it directly to C:\ . Amazingly, that did the trick and MDS now runs. For anyone else having MDS issues, here's a troubleshooting link:

http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800792/801079/Support_-_BlackBerry_Mobile_Data_Service_Simulator_does_not_launch.html?nodeid=800979&vernum=0

Comment: Thanks for the update! I have long since resolved this issue on my PC. I am developing in Eclipse, and the Blackberry simulator is also installed as an Eclipse plugin. I run MDS directly from the Eclipse plugin directory (C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.25\components\MDS). Note that I am running Windows 7 and therefore have to startup my command prompt in Admin mode. Not the most elegant solution but it works for me.